# Checking mod_python library version on CentOS7

Tags: php, apache, centos, mod-python

I'm new to Linux and LAMP stack.

I'm trying to install [PyAuthenNTLM2](https://github.com/Legrandin/PyAuthenNTLM2) on CentOS 7.8 VM.
One of it's prerequisites is to have **mod_python**  installed.
However, I'm not sure if this **mod_python** is already installed or not.

I found one rpm file for mod_python on one of older CentOS 6 VM. However it seems it's not compatible with CentOS 7.

This is what I tried on CentOS 7:

```
rpm -ivh mod_python-3.3.1-14.el6.1.x86_64.rpm
```

However this failed with the following error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
      httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by mod_python-3.3.1-14.el6.1.x86_64
      libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by mod_python-3.3.1-14.el6.1.x86_64
      python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by mod_python-3.3.1-14.el6.1.x86_64
```

I have Python 2.7 and  Apache 2.4.6 installed on this Cent OS 7.8 VM.

How can we check if **mod_python** is installed and check it's corresponding version?

Or any better alternative to enable NTLM auth on Apache instead of using PyAuthenNTLM2?

Comment: How about `mod_python2.7-3.5.0` from the " *home:matthewdva:mod_python.repo* "  https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/matthewdva%3A/mod_python/CentOS_7/home%3Amatthewdva%3Amod_python.repo ......... Ref. https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/matthewdva%3A/mod_python/CentOS_7/

Comment: @KnudLarsen sure will give this a try. 
But any idea on a specific command (or base directory location) through which I can check the version of mod_python installed on my machine?

Comment: mod_python : Python interpreter for the Apache HTTP Server. .... Fedora 17 file example `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_python.so` . Same as the suggested **el7** package.

Comment: Version : Search installed mod_python : `rpm -qa mod_python` ...... More info : `rpm -qi mod_python`